Regarding convergence rates, is it important to distinguish between convergence rate of $(x^t)$ and $(f(x^t))$?
Right now I am dealing with iteration complexity of different gradient descent and stochastic gradient descent algorithms. Most of the time one assumes (strongly) convex objectives and smooth gradients for these objectives.
I am confused that some people proof some convergence property for $\lVert x^t - x_{opt} \rVert$ and some other for $\lVert f(x^t) - f(x_{opt}) \rVert$ but they in both cases than just say "Oh yeah this algorithm needs $\mathcal{O}(...)$ iterations for $\epsilon$-accuracy.
Does it matter in terms of $\mathcal{O}(..)$ notation if I showed the convergence rate inside the domain or the image space?
